# How do charges "flow"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

I just started current electricity and then almost all textbooks I read defined current as flow of charge and gave it as $I=q/t$.
In electrostatics I learnt that conductors are equipotential and there is no electric field inside them as charges can rearrange and solved numerous problems using that fact.
But if this is the case then how does current flow in conductors.
Note:All I know is electrostatics.
I asked this question to people and they replied that this is not an electrostatic situation.
But I didn't understand what they meant. I am sure flaw is with the assumptions of equipotentiality of metals but I cant justify

Comment: Those people are correct. Charges flowing means it is not electroSTATIC. There will be electric field inside the conductor proportional to the current (Ohm's Law), and that means many different equipotential surfaces inside the conductor, not just one equipotential for the entire conductor like in electrostatics.